# Longest Common Subsequence taking maximum of all the three possible cases

Tags: algorithm

I approached the Longest Common Subsequence as:

```
LCS(m,n) = max( LCS(m-1,n), LCS(m,n-1), LCS(m-1,n-1) + (String1[m]==String2[n]) );
```

Whereas the texts show the logic for the problem to be like:

```
if( String1[m]==String2[n] )
    LCS(m,n) = LCS(m-1,n-1) + 1;
else LCS(m,n) = max( LCS(m-1,n), LCS(m,n-1) );
```

Will my approach produce incorrect results? if yes, then in what kind of a situation? If it is correct, how do you justify the correctness?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it will work. Draw a table and check it.

Comment: At any entry in the table I cannot find an entry such that LCS(m-1,n-1) > LCS(m-1,n) or LCS(m-1,n-1) > LCS(m,n-1). I'm still working on a solid proof though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My (badly) Java version, it runs correctly?

```
//'main' method must be in a class 'Rextester'.
//Compiler version 1.8.0_111

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] a = {1,1,1,1,2,3,2,3};
        int[] b = {1,1,1,1,3,4,3,4};
        System.out.println(solve(a, b).toString());
        System.out.println(solve2(a, b).toString());
    }

    private static void printL(int[][]len, int m, int n, int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        System.out.print("  a→ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            System.out.print(a[j]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            if (i > 0) { System.out.print(" "); System.out.print(b[i-1]); System.out.print(" "); }
            else { System.out.print("b↓ "); }
            for (int j = 0; j <= m; ++j)
            {
                System.out.print(len[i][j]);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static List<Integer> solve(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        int m = a.length;
        int n = b.length;
        System.out.println("Method 1");

        int[][] len = new int[n+1][m+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                len[i+1][j+1] = a[j] == b[i] ? 1 + len[i][j] : Math.max(len[i+1][j], len[i][j+1]);
        printL(len, m, n, a, b);


        List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = n - 1, j = m - 1; len[i+1][j+1] > 0;)
        {
            if (a[j] == b[i]) { c.add(a[j]); i--; j--; }
            else if (len[i+1][j] < len[i][j+1]) i--;
            else j--;
        }
        Collections.reverse(c);
        return c;
    }

    private static List<Integer> solve2(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        int m = a.length;
        int n = b.length;
        System.out.println("Method 2");

        int[][] len = new int[n+1][m+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                len[i+1][j+1] = Math.max(Math.max(len[i+1][j], len[i][j+1]), (a[j] == b[i] ? 1 : 0) + len[i][j]);
        printL(len, m, n, a, b);

        List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = n - 1, j = m - 1; len[i+1][j+1] > 0;)
        {
            if (a[j] == b[i]) { c.add(a[j]); i--; j--; }
            else if (len[i+1][j] < len[i][j+1]) i--;
            else j--;
        }
        Collections.reverse(c);
        return c;
    }
}
```

output on rextester:

```
Method 1
  a→ 1 1 1 1 2 3 2 3 
b↓ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
 1 0 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 
 1 0 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 
 3 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 
 4 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 
 3 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 
 4 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
Method 2
  a→ 1 1 1 1 2 3 2 3 
b↓ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
 1 0 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 
 1 0 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 
 3 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 
 4 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 
 3 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 
 4 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

My sketchy proof:

If you look at any row LCS(m) in the table above, you'll see that they all have increasing values, or they're all monotonically increasing. They cannot be decreasing since LCS(m,n) means longest common subsequence of (sub)string1 of length m and (sub)string2 of length n, if n2 >= n1 then LCS(m,n2) >= LCS(m,n1) because if n2 >= n1, LCS(m,n2) contains LCS(m,n1).

For the column LCS(n) you use the same proof. Now you have LCS(m,n) <= LCS(m,n+1) and LCS(m,n) <= LCS(m+1,n), which means your taking maximum of all three possible cases are correct.

`LCS(m,n) = max( LCS(m-1,n), LCS(m,n-1), LCS(m-1,n-1) + (String1[m]==String2[n]) );`
  takes the wrong path only when `String1[m] != String2[n]` and `(LCS(m-1,n-1) > LCS(m,n-1)` or `LCS(m-1,n-1) > LCS(m-1,n))`, but the latter case `(LCS(m-1,n-1) > LCS(m,n-1)` or `LCS(m-1,n-1) > LCS(m-1,n))` never happens. So your approach is correct.

Comment: nice one! also, we can say that abs(LCS(m,n-1) - LCS(m-1,n-1)) <= 1.